# K Paths between two nodes in a network

Tags: graph-theory

Hi there.. I have a network (a graph undirected and unweighted) and I need to find k-paths between any pair of nodes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

my understanding that this basically can be done by linear programming, as a variation of the classical max-flow min-cut approach. See this [paper](http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~gravin/Papers/k-path_camera.pdf) in J. Graph Theory 67(2011) 34-37.

Needless to say, in the non-directed case one can replace each edge by a pair of arcs going in opposite directions.

Comment: but in my case, the graph is undirected and unweighted. In your paper, the theorem uses a directed and weighted graph.


Comment: so your case is a subcase of the situation considered in the paper!